# Detect when vimeo video pauses

Tags: javascript, c#, vimeo-api

I am playing a series of vimeo videos on an external website (I do not have access to the source code) and they keep pausing during playback. I have to manually click on the play button when the video pauses. I have code that can perform a mouse-click on a defined area but I need to detect when the icon on the vimeo player changes from "play" to "pause". I know there is a JavaScript API that listens for player events (https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api) but I know nothing about this API. It may not even do what I require.
Maybe a C# app is a better option?

Comment: Are you able to determine why is it pausing?

Answer (score 2):

To detect when the video is paused you can use:

```
function onFinish(id) {
    alert('video has paused');
    console.log('video has paused');
}

player.addEvent('pause', onFinish);
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/felipekm/vy9kf0w5/10/)

Comment: Thanks felipe, that is a start except the iFrame that contains the vimeo video does not have an id attribute, just a "src" attribute.

Comment: I found another JSFiddle that might assist me:http://jsfiddle.net/bdougherty/UTt2K/light/